# Can't choose an existing server in a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, server

My colleague just set up a Dynamic Web Project in Eclipse and he also configured the server. He shared the entire project on a git repository and I cloned it. When I try to run the HTML file I click on 'run on server' but then I'm not able to choose an existing server already configured. Eclipse forces me to create a new server with default configuration.

[image: image of eclipse]

Comment: Did you actually configure a server?

Comment: My friend configured it before the git push

Comment: The server is not part of the project. You need to configure it for every workspace. Do you even have an application server/web container on your device?

Comment: Thanks, but is there a way to avoid to modify all the files every time? I use Tomcat.

Comment: Essentially my question is: how can i create a server for my workspace with the configuration of  'Tomcat v9.0 Server at localhost-config' in Servers fold (which is the already configured server)?

Comment: I think you can export the server configuration and import it later but the actual server needs to be installed in the same location.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Right click on you project and go to properties. Go to Project Facets and on Dynamic Web Module click the little drop down menu and select 3.1. I initially had it at 4.0 and it was not supported in my version of Eclipse.

Answer (score 1):

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ipqTnzTPgj0

Help --> Install new software ---> install " eclipse repository - https://download.eclipse.org/releases/oxygen ".
Then install the package for -- Web,XML, Java EE and OSGi Enterprise Development.
Reboot your computer and eclipse. Then it will work. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

It works for me:

Properties -> Project Facets and do it like this

[image]